# Efficient algorithm to count number of substrings divisible by 3

Tags: c++, algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given a string of decimal digits, I have to find the number of all substrings divisible by 3 in the range L to R [both inclusive], where L & R are index[1-based] of the specified string
`string length <= 100000`

I've tried the Naive approach of iterating over all possible substrings & obtaining the answer, but that is not fast enough, especially for multiple pairs L & R.

Then I tried a DP approach. I can obtain all possible substrings divisible by 3 in the whole string, i.e. I'm unable to code the DP solution that gives result for given range.
DP Solution that I tried (not completely sure about It):

```
for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
    for(j=0 ; j<3 ; j++) {
        dp[i][j]=0 ;
    }
    int curr = (input[i]-'0')%3 ;
    dp[i][curr]++ ;
    if(i) {
        for(j=0 ; j<3 ; j++) {
            if(curr % 3 == 0) { dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][j]; }
            if(curr % 3 == 1) { dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][(j+2)%3]; }
            if(curr % 3 == 2) { dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][(j+1)%3]; }
        }
    }
}
long long sum = 0;
for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++) { sum += dp[i][0] ; }
```

Can this solution be modified to give results for given range [L,R] ?

After searching alot, I learnt that range queries problems are solved by Segment Tree, but I'm unsure as how Segment Tree + Lazy Propagation can help in this question.

So what is a performant way to count all substrings divisible by 3 in the range L to R [both inclusive]?

**EDIT:**
Input: First Line contains the given string. Lines after that contain two integers denoting L and R respectively, where both L and R are index(1-based) of string.

> Input:
>   
>   `301524
>   1 2
>   4 6
>   3 5`
>
> Output:
>   
>   `3
>   1
>   1`
>
> Explanation:
>   When L=1 & R=2 we get 3 possible substrings, `{3}, {0}, {30}` & all these when considered as a decimal number are divisible by 3. Hence the output.
>   When L=4 & R=6 we get 6 possible substrings, `{5} , {52}, {524}, {2}, {24}, {4}` & out of these only `{24}` is divisible by 3.

Repetitions in substrings like 3333 count multiple times, so for L=1 to R=4 the answer would be 10, since we have four times 3, three times 33, two times 333 and one time 3333 (all divisible by 3).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your explanation of the problem. Could you give some sample inputs and outputs perhaps? For example, if the string was "31012" would the substrings be "3" and "12" and the correct answer 15?

Comment: Of note, your `{}` are mismatched. Where does the `ll` part belong?  I assume that `ll` is a `long long`, but that isn't defined in the example.

Comment: I've made the edits.

Comment: It may possibly be helpful in finding efficient algorithms to solve this to realise that if a number is divisible by 3 then so is the sum of all the digits in its decimal representation.

Comment: I will point out one clue, and this should be enough for some clever audience to figure out the right way to apply dynamic programming (DP) to this question. In the above example "301524", if one breaks down into substrings `{ "3", "0", "15", "24" }`, does it make it slightly more obvious how these candidates could be summarized? Note that alignment is not unique; for example, in a string "111111111111", every substring of "111" is a fragment candidate. This non-uniqueness is what makes dynamic programming outperform the brute-force. That said ***I'm not advocating against brute-force***.

Comment: Aha. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string (thanks @rwong)

Comment: Good exercise ... took me 4 hours to code a (seemingly) correct solution with dynamic programming with `O(N)`. Seems not quite a "beginner level" question.

Comment: I am not sure that there is a solution faster than O(n log n), because from what I can tell brute force is the only way to do this without further constraints on the problem domain.

Comment: @DocBrown : I've made the edits. We have to print count of number of substrings divisible by 3. Hope It is clear now.

Comment: @DocBrown : Sorry. It's edited now. Previously I made the edits to last line.

Comment: @DocBrown: Ans will be 10 in this case..

Comment: @Aalok: I changed your question according to your comments (better to place important information there instead of hiding it here several paragraphs below). Hope I got it right.

Comment: Based on an informant's comment this question is a rephrase or a sub-component of a programming contest currently taking place. The content is expected to end on Jan 15, 2015. (That said, the algorithmic specification of this question has been published for more than a half year, therefore it would have been contestant's personal responsibility to not violate the rules.) [Link to contest page](http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/QSET)

Comment: For the related question that looks for divisibility by `M` (not fixed, to be provided as input), it uses the formula `(A * B + C) mod M == ((A mod M) * (B mod M) + (C mod M)) mod M`. Also, residual system can be used, for example if `B == 10` (decimal) and `M == 11` (thus looking for divisibility by 11), `B mod M` can be taken as either `10` (the traditional way) or `-1` (for the purpose of cranking out the solution). For large `M`, higher powers of `B` can also be used.

Comment: For example, let's say divisibility by 7. We want to calculate the concatenation of two strings "1234" and "5678" (giving "12345678") when we already have "1234 mod 7 == 2" and "5678 mod 7 == 1". The result is "2 * (10000 mod 7) + 1", where "(10000 mod 7)" is further calculated from ((((1 * 3 + 0) * 3 + 0) * 3 + 0) * 3 + 0) mod 7 == 4. so, "12345678 mod 7" == (2 * 4 + 1) mod 7 == 2.

Comment: (I would post this as an answer if I could, but my sign-up reputation hasn't filtered through yet...) This is very simple: you just need to go once through the string, keeping track of the number of times the total so far is equal to 0, 1, or 2 mod 3. (You need to start off with the empty string, which sums to 0 mod 3.) Suppose there are 7 instances of 1 mod 3....

Comment: ...Then any substring that starts just after one of these instances, and ends at another one, is divisible by 3. So they contribute (7*6)/2=21 to the total. The same for instances of 0 and 2 mod 3. Thus you only need four variables (apart from the loop counter): total so far (mod 3); and number of totals equal to 0, 1, and 2 (mod 3). Then at the end the answer is ((zeroes * (zeroes - 1)) + (ones * (ones - 1)) + (twos * (twos - 1))) / 2.

Answer (score 6):

Cute dynamic programming problem. Here is a Java solution and quick explanation.

The basic question to ask yourself is if I knew subproblem X, I could solve solve problem Y easily.

In this case, problem Y is the number of substrings divisible by 3, the subproblem X is the number of substrings modulo 3 that terminate at the previous character for each possible mod (that is remained 0, 1, and 2).

If you know that at the previous position, there were 2 substrings that terminated there that had a residue of zero, 3 with a residue of one, and 1 with a residue of two, then given the current number and its residue, it is trivial to determine the residues of all the strings that terminate at the current character.

If the current number's residue is one (e.g., the number is 1, 4, or 7), then the substrings terminating on the previous number with a residue of one now have a residue of two, those with a residue of two now have a residue of zero, and those with a residue of zero now have a residue of one plus 1 more for the current digit since you added a new possible substring of length one.

For example, if you had the string 521438 and you knew the number of strings terminating at the 3 for each residue (2, 2, and 1 respectively for residues 0, 1, and 2), and since 8 mod 3 is 2, you know that all those with residue zero now have residue 2, those with residue two now have residue one, and those with residue one now have residue zero, so (2, 1, and 2 repectively), plus you have a new string of residue 2 so you have 2, 1, and 3 now including the current number.

After you process this in linear time, for all the substrings, you add up the all those with residue zero terminating in all locations.

Here is the code:

```
// Takes constant space and linear time.
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // You really only need these numbers mod 3.
    int[] s = new int [] { 5,8,1,4,6,2 };
    int left = 3;
    int right = 4;

    int[] found = new int[3];
    int[] last_found = new int[3];
    int sum_found = 0;

    for(int i = left; i <= right; ++i) {

        int res = s[i-1] % 3;

        // leaving the +0 just to show the symmetry.
        // Basically, rotate by the residue and +1 for the new substring.
        // This can be done as a single array, but this is clearer I think.
        // (Also, a proper mathematical modulus would be easier too.)
        found[(res+0) % 3] = last_found[0] + 1;
        found[(res+1) % 3] = last_found[1];
        found[(res+2) % 3] = last_found[2];

        sum_found += found[0];

        // Swap the current and last arrays to make top of the loop simpler.
        int[] swap = last_found;
        last_found = found; 
        found = swap;
    }

    System.out.println( sum_found );
}
```

### Code Edit

The code above removed the table and just keeps track of the last position. It does this with two arrays of length three and swapping between them. It could  be done with a single array, but it makes the code more complex (and probably doesn't even perform better in the micro-optimization sense either).

It is now linear time and constant space while obeying the Left and Right requests. It is like a number of other DP algorithms, if you notice each iteration you are only looking back the the Ith-1 iterations, then you can usually elide the full table.

It also keeps track of the sum along with way (now required since the final array doesn't exist anymore either). I didn't fully understand the problem at first, and it appears to have gone through some edits along the way.

Comment: I think you saw the question of previous edits. Someone made the wrong edits. Sorry for that. I did this DP solution to get count of all substrings divisible by 3 in whole string but the question is to find the count of substrings in given range [L,R]. Is it possible to make changes to this DP solution so that we can get count in given range? Please check the question again because I've made the edits in It.

Comment: So you want to process once and query multiple times? Can't you take this solution then process forward once and backwards once. Now you know how many substrings are divisive by 3 that start at a position too. Make the cumulative sum of each array and do the math? I'll do it tomorrow if nobody does. Alternatively you add another dimension and an inner loop to keep track of starting positions too.

Comment: +1 you can avoid storing in an 3*n-array `tab` if you do the summation of `all` already in the for loop. Then you only need a three element array tab

Comment: @brown so for calculating the 1-10^5 we need to add all the data.Is anybody having any idea how segment tree help here on decreasing the query time (as in case of segment tree this answer can be given in O(1))?

Comment: @RATHI you can preprocess it in quadratic time and get constant time lookups with just a simple table approach I'm pretty sure. At worst, the lookup would be linear w.r.t the size of the substring.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python solution to the problem. It is basically the same as the solution of @JasonN. It also implements a function that returns the value for different pairs of L and R. It uses less memory when doing the precalculations. You can run it [here](http://ideone.com/I5QUUn)

```
#http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/268022/51441


# s:
#   input digit string that should be checked
# L:
#   the start of the substring that should be investigated
# L:
#   the end of the substring that should be investigated
# cnt:
#   number of 3divisble substrings found so far
# ss0:
#   number of substrings that end at the current position
#   and are divisible by 3
# ss1:
#   number of substrings that end at the current position
#   and have the remainder 1 when divided by 3
# ss2:
#   number of substrings that end at the current position
#   and have the remainder 2 when divided by 3


def ss(s,L,R):
    cnt=0
    (ss0,ss1,ss2)=(0,0,0)
    for i in range(L,R+1):
        r=int(s[i])%3
        if r==0:
            ss0+=1
        elif r==1:
            (ss0,ss1,ss2)=(ss2,ss0,ss1)
            ss1+=1
        elif r==2:
            (ss0,ss1,ss2)=(ss1,ss2,ss0)
            ss2+=1
        cnt+=ss0
    return(cnt)

print(ss('392301',0,len('392301')-1))
print(ss('2035498',2,5))
```

Comment: Same as mine now. I didn't understand only one query was needed, but after removing the full table, they come down to the same thing (in both space and time, I just make the arrays explicit). The Python multiple assignment definitely makes it simple. I like that.

Comment: ss_cnt[R] - ss_cnt[L-1] isn't going to return the number of substrings divisible by 3 within that range. Subtracting ss_cnt[L-1] doesn't remove the substrings that start before L and end between L and R (inclusive).

Comment: For example for the string '2035498', ss(2,5) will return 9 whereas the actual answer is 6

Comment: @Rushil you are right, I will try to  repair this as soon as possible.

Comment: @Rushil the error is removed now but the running time is now O(n) for each function call

Comment: yes it will be. To reduce the running time to O(log n) you could use a segment tree

Comment: @Rushil thank you for this hint. From comments to the  OP I learned that this is a problem from a running programming contest. Therefore I will not pursue this problem further.

Comment: @Rushil : I'll want to know about Segment Tree solution after that Live Contest end.

Comment: @Aalok sure! Codechef will however be posting an editorial for this problem. You can check out the contest page after the contest ends.

Answer (score 0):

We know *A number is divisble by 3 if the sum of its digits is divisble by 3* (according to the divisibility rules of 3). There is `O(n^2)` dynamic programming solution (pre-processing) and `O(1)` constant time for each query.

Let `arr[i]` is array containing given elements (`1....N`) and `query[i][j]` denotes # of substrings divisible by 3 from `[i, j]`

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    query[i][i] = (arr[i] % 3 == 0); // i.e. # of substrings divisible by 3 in [4, 4] is 1 if arr[4] is divisble by 3 otherwise 0
    arr[i] += arr[i - 1]; // arr[i] will contain cumulative sum of 1...i
}

// 
for(int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j <= N; j++) {
        // exclusion-inclusion principle. # of substrings in [1, 7] will be - 
        // #1 sum of # of substrings in [1, 6] and [2, 7]. 
        //    As [2, 6] is included two times, so we need to subtract it one time
        // #2 plus 1 if substring [1, 7] is divisble by 3, 0 otherwise

        // #1
        query[i][j] = query[i][j - 1] + query[i + 1][j] - query[i + 1][j - 1];
        // #2
        // arr[j] contains sum of 1...j. 
        // so arr[j] - arr[i - 1] contains sum of [i...j]
        // number constructed from substring [i...j] is divisble by 3 
        // iff summation of its digits is divible by 3
        query[i][j] += ((arr[j] - arr[i - 1]) % 3 == 0);
    }
}
```

Note: This will work when the # of elements (`Range`) is within `3 * 10^3`. Otherwise the declation of `query[Range][Range]` will show compilation error.

If you still don't get what's happening on those loopings, use pen and paper to draw a 2D table and fill it up according to above calculation. Then you will surely get a clear intuition :)

Comment: Can you explain what is happening inside j loop?  
Little more explanation regarding how `query[i][j]` is obtained..

Comment: @Aalok check the edits